# how to caluclate the no of characters in the particular environment in latex

Tags: environments, output, word-count

IS possible to check the character count is more than 1800 character in the particular environment? if it is greater than that it should be thrown the error? how to achieve this?

my MWE is

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{gray}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.3}
\newbox\absbox
\newbox\tempbox
\newdimen\tempdima

\newenvironment{abstract}{\global\setbox\absbox\vbox\bgroup}{\egroup}

\def\printabstract{\par%
                    \setbox\tempbox\hbox{Keywords}%Zusammenfassung
                        \tempdima\wd\tempbox%
                        \advance\tempdima4.2mm%
                        \advance\tempdima4.2mm%
                        \noindent\fboxsep0pt\colorbox{gray}{\vbox to 13pt{\hsize\tempdima\vfill\noindent\hspace*{4.2mm}Abstract\vfill}}
                         \endgraf\vspace*{2.8pt}%
                         {\noindent\ignorespaces\unvcopy\absbox\endgraf}
                 }




\begin{abstract}
Using the standard definitions of EVM and ES, we established a sound theoretical basis for the prediction of the project duration when the cost profiles follow a Gompertz function. We  derived formulas for the duration estimates and found the important and interesting result that a simple 2-point estimation formula is effective in predicting the duration early in the project.

In conclusion, we established a new, effective method of duration and cost estimation over time and validated the theory by comparing its predictions to many synthetic projects. The duration and cost error formulas are quite simple and require little additional effort to project teams to be practically useful in the context of project monitoring and control.

In conclusion, we established a new, effective method of duration and cost estimation over time and validated the theory by comparing its predictions to many synthetic projects. The duration and cost error formulas are quite simple and require little additional effort to project teams to be practically useful in the context of project monitoring and control.
\end{abstract}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

Text, Text, Text, Text,


\section{Section 1}

\printabstract


\section{Section 2}

\printabstract \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it is actually counting are non-space tokens.  I introduce the `countenv` environment with the syntax

```
\begin{countenv}[<error-msg prepend>]{environment name}
```

Thus, `\begin{countenv}{abstract}` is sufficient to give a proper error message if the `abstract` exceeds the limit.  However, `\begin{countenv}[\item]{itemize}` requires the optional argument, because any error message must be set with an `\item` prepended to the error message.

The environmental size limit is set in the counter `charlim`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{environ}
\newcounter{charcount}
\newcounter{charlim}
\setcounter{charlim}{1800}
\NewEnviron{countenv}[2][]{%
  \setcounter{charcount}{0}%
  \expandafter\countem\BODY\relax\EOE
  \relax%
  \ifnum\value{charcount}<\value{charlim}\relax
    \begin{#2}\BODY\end{#2}
  \else
    \begin{#2}#1 \thecharcount{} letters in the ``#2'' exceeds
       \thecharlim{} character limit\end{#2}
  \fi
}

\long\def\countem#1#2\EOE{%
  \stepcounter{charcount}%
  \ifx\relax#2
    \def\next{\relax}%
  \else
    \def\next{\countem#2\EOE}%
  \fi
  \expandafter\next%
}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{gray}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.3}
\newbox\absbox
\newbox\tempbox
\newdimen\tempdima

\newenvironment{abstract}{\global\setbox\absbox\vbox\bgroup}{\egroup}

\def\printabstract{\par%
                    \setbox\tempbox\hbox{Keywords}%Zusammenfassung
                        \tempdima\wd\tempbox%
                        \advance\tempdima4.2mm%
                        \advance\tempdima4.2mm%
                        \noindent\fboxsep0pt\colorbox{gray}{\vbox to 13pt{\hsize\tempdima\vfill\noindent\hspace*{4.2mm}Abstract\vfill}}
                         \endgraf\vspace*{2.8pt}%
                         {\noindent\ignorespaces\unvcopy\absbox\endgraf}
                 }

\begin{countenv}{abstract}
Using the standard definitions of EVM and ES, we established a sound theoretical basis for the prediction of the project duration when the cost profiles follow a Gompertz function. We  derived formulas for the duration estimates and found the important and interesting result that a simple 2-point estimation formula is effective in predicting the duration early in the project.

In conclusion, we established a new, effective method of duration and cost estimation over time and validated the theory by comparing its predictions to many synthetic projects. The duration and cost error formulas are quite simple and require little additional effort to project teams to be practically useful in the context of project monitoring and control.

In conclusion, we established a new, effective method of duration and cost estimation over time and validated the theory by comparing its predictions to many synthetic projects. The duration and cost error formulas are quite simple and require little additional effort to project teams to be practically useful in the context of project monitoring and control.
\end{countenv}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

Text, Text, Text, Text,

\section{Section 1}

\printabstract

\section{Section 2}

\begin{countenv}[\item]{itemize}
\item this is a test

\item another test

\item a final test
\end{countenv} 

\end{document}
```

With a 20 character limit, `\setcounter{charlim}{20}`:

[image]

Note that the 37 letters reported in the `itemize` environment are actually 32 alphanumeric letters, plus 2 `\par` tokens and 3 `\item` tokens (which in this case produce bullets, but may, in other cases like `enumerate`, each produce multi-character outputs).

---

With an 800 character limit, `\setcounter{charlim}{800}`:

[image]

---

With an 1800 charcter limit, `\setcounter{charlim}{1800}`:

[image]